# dbname PDO issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, idiorm

I am having a weird issue setting up a site with SlimPHP and [Idiorm/Paris](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/).

Basically none of the generated queries are working because MySQL is still requiring a database identifier.

For example: `SELECT * FROM table`  fails , but `SELECT * FROM dbname.table` works.

```
ORM::configure('mysql:host=myhostname;dbname=mydbname;');
ORM::configure('username', $username);
ORM::configure('password', $password);
```

I set the `dbname` properly in the connection many times over using both a built string and manually. It connects find and appears to be using that schema.

I really don't want to hack together a forced "using" into the [Idiorm](http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/) module but if that is the only answer so be it.

**Notes:**

1. GoDaddy Hosting (*I suspect this is the issue*) LAMP stack
2. The `dbname` and `username` are the same

Comment: I'm not familiar with Idiorm, but your connect string is correct for PDO.  Looking at the Idiorm documentation, your code looks correct.  I suspect your problem isn't with the code here.  Make a small script to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a godaddy issue like I suspected..
apparently they default non-direct connections which I missed somehow.

Hopefully this can prevent someone else's misery in the future!